# Would there be no input or input does not exist?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, inverse, ceiling-and-floor-functions

This problem is from *Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications*.
[image]

And the definition of inverse from the book:[image]

For part 43 (c), would the inverse not exist? For the floor function, in terms of $f(a) = b$, there is no $a$ that will get you a value between $0$(exclusive) and 1(exclusive) because, by definition, the floor function returns an integer? Therefore the inverse ($0 < x < 1$) will not exist.

Comment: Are you sure this problem isn't asking about the preimage of $g$, instead of its inverse (which isn't a function)?

Comment: The problem uses the inverse sign doesn't it?

Comment: Unfortunately, the same symbol is used. See [here](https://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Preimage) for a definition.

Comment: preimage is just a set, not a function?

Answer (score 0):

You are very close.

The correct answer is not really "does not exist" but ___.

Comment: if it's does not exist, it exists?

Comment: To me it has to be does not exist, because the floor function maps to an Integer that is  less than or equal to the value.